# Receiving a 'Not found. Authentication passthru.' error for Devise omniauthable with namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I've never received this error until I tried to use oauth via a namespaced controller - not sure if it's a coincidence or there is an issue here. Any help is appreciated!

Here are some relevant code snippets.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users,
            class_name: 'Accounts::User',
            path: 'accounts',
            controllers: {
              omniauth_callbacks: 'accounts/omniauth_callbacks',
              registrations: 'accounts/registrations'
            }
```

accounts/user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
        omniauth_providers: %i[facebook google_oauth2]
```

accounts/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
module Accounts
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
      sign_in user_from_auth_hash
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Facebook authentication successful.'
    end
  end
end
```

initializers/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/accounts/auth'
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_OAUTH_ID'],
  ENV['FACEBOOK_OAUTH_SECRET']
```

Let me know if there's anything else to add. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the segment from the logs from when you start the authentication process?

Comment: There's not much to the logs, just this:

Started GET "/accounts/auth/facebook" for ::1 at 2021-01-22 20:49:04 -0500
Processing by Accounts::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru as HTML
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 25)
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 510)